# Issue with indentation using bootstrap Container class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.left-text {
 margin-right : 25%;
 margin-left : 5%;
}

.img-left {
 z-index : 10 ;
}

.color-overlap-right {
 background-color : #d93;
 margin-right : -25%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
  <div class="color-overlap-right">
   <div class="left-text">
    <h1 id="heading">Top 8 reasons</h1>

   </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 img-left" style="background-color:lavender;">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/1.PNG" alt="1">
 </div> 
  </div>
```

I am trying to make below HTML layout

[image]

Here is how my layout looks like. Entire content on the page is left aligned as shown in image. However there are image and color boxes going outside the width of container. I am facing issue in aligning the content inside the div spanning across entire width to indent along with the text in above column. Can someone please provide me hints?

**Edit 1**

This answer has been marked duplicate. However just want to add that height of column 1 is more than column 2. Also image in column 2 overlaps the color in column 1. In the solution you have provided, background color is applied to entire parent row which is overwritten in 2nd column by different color which is not case in my scenario.

**Edit 2**

[image: Here is what i am trying to achieve]

Comment: Can you update your code in fiddle.

Comment: put some code you did

Comment: NEED code to help!

Comment: @Banzay code added

Comment: @Banzay Answer you have marked is not duplicate of question i have asked. I need height of column 1 in row 2 to be more than the image. It would not work with the solution you have provided

Comment: I choose another reason, not duplicate. it was gold-badged member desicion

Comment: anyway try  to set orange background color to row.

Comment: @Banzay can't set complete row color since Text and Image are part of 2 columns and height of 1st Column text is more than image in 2nd column

Comment: @ZimSystem Please review duplicate Tag. I have reviewed solution and its not duplicate. Please help